# GET Request query always empty

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have wrote a function to check whether an email is unique or not within a collection. The issue, is that I have a GET request hooked onto this function, but the function's req.query is always empty.

My request looks like this: us-central1/users?email=mymail@test.com

I've tried doing this without Express, then I added Express, the same issue occurs.

Complete code: (deploying locally with `npm run deploy`)

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = require('express')();

app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

initializeApp();
const fireStore = firestore();

const checkUserName = (req: any, res: any) => {
    if (req.method !== 'GET') {
        return res.status(405).send(`${req.method} is not allowed`);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.query));
    if (!req.query.hasOwnProperty('email')) {
        return res.status(400).send('Email not provided');
    }

    const email = req.query.email;

    if (email.trim().length === 0) {
        return res.status(400).send('Invalid email address');
    }

    fireStore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(email)
        .get()
        .then((doc: any) => {
            return res.status(200).send(doc);
        })
        .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
};

app.get('/', checkUserName);

exports.users = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct URL to call the function, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#invoke_an_http_function? You should use an url like https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/users?email=mymail@test.com

Comment: Instead of showing several snippets of code, please show the entire, minimal code segment that illustrates what you're doing.  We should be able to duplicate this for ourselves.  Also please be very clear about the URL you're using to invoke the function.  The URL you're showing now is just a URL fragment.

Comment: Added complete code, and mentioned that I run it locally.

Comment: It's interesting that when I deploy locally, it doesn't recognize the email parameter. Regardless of how I do it. But when I deploy to the cloud, it works.